# Не работает удаление комментария

Tags: jquery, javascript

```
<script>
function deleteComent(id){
    $('.comments').hide(1000);
}
</script>
```

Вот код, где использую id

```
if ($email == $d['email']) {
    $delete_comment = '<div onClick="deleteComent('
         .$id_comment
         .')" style="position:absolute; cursor:pointer; margin-left:480px; margin-top:-13px;"><img src="images/delete_comment.png" onmouseover=\'this.src="images/delete_comment2.png";\' 
    onmouseout=\'this.src="images/delete_comment.png";\'></div>';
}
```

Comment: jquery подключен? div с классом comments есть? Нафиг функции аргумент id, если он не используется?

Comment: id используется, jquery подключен.

Comment: И где же он используется?
__Разберитесь вы уже в азах.__

Answer (score 1):

Круто. `$('.comments').hide(1000);` используете а сами комменты отсутствуют. И причем прячете все комменты, вне зависимости от id. Или я чего-то недопонял? Тогда выложите больше кода.

Comment: @ling - чего тут можно "недопонять"? Аффтар - нуп =)

PS: за такой PHP код нужно руки отрывать, а лучше сразу вешать =)

Comment: AlexWindHope ах ты маленький извращенец

Comment: кстати проблема уже решена всем спасибо за ответы!